# How can i have the form text empty?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I dont know the way to leave the the form text empty is there is no result.I need something like this.....

> If there is no userCreator =  form text empty

My code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('userCreator','UserCreator') }}
        @if(isset($userCreator))
        @foreach($userCreator as $cs)
        {{ Form::text('userCreator',$cs->home_lastname,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
        @endforeach
        @else{ {{-- What should i put inside here ? --}}
        }
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ...

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('userCreator','UserCreator') }}
        @if(!empty($userCreator))
          @foreach($userCreator as $cs)
            {{ Form::text('userCreator',$cs->home_lastname,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
          @endforeach
        @else
            {{ Form::text('userCreator','', ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@if(isset($userCreator) && count($userCreator) > 0)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('userCreator','UserCreator') }}
            @foreach($userCreator as $cs)
            {{ Form::text('userCreator',$cs->home_lastname,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: i want to show nothing if there is no result...@AlexeyMezenin

Comment: Please look at updated code. If I understood you correctly, it will work for you.